# Return header view for section but not for other

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to return a header for a section but not for another.

What do I return?

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.section == RDSectionRecipeDetail) {
        /*create view here*/
        return myView
    }else{
        //What to return when I dont want a view?
        return ?;
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake. Read the docs: "This method must always return a valid view object. If you do not want a supplementary view in a particular case, your layout object should not create the attributes for that view. Alternatively, you can hide views by setting the hidden property of the corresponding attributes to YES or set the alpha property of the attributes to 0. To hide header and footer views in a flow layout, you can also set the width and height of those views to 0."

Comment: what about `return nil`? ...just saying

Comment: @staticVoidMan Read the docs for `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`.

Comment: oh, `You must not return nil from this method`. ok, my bad

Comment: so @rmaddy, create a dummyView, either set it's frame to zero size &/or set it's hidden property to YES and return the view?

Answer (score 1):

This is my current approach

```
   - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
         UICollectionReusableView *headerView = nil;
         headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"collectionHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader && indexPath.section != 0) {
            headerView.hidden = YES;
        }
     else{
            headerView.hidden = NO;
         }
         return headerView;
     }
```